# Facebook comments are duplicated on every page

Tags: facebook, comments

I am trying to integrate facebook comments into my website (I tried to do it several months ago but there didn't seem much support about and I couldn't fathom it).  The comments are showing and I managed to get the comment to show on my facebook wall under the individual post/item they were meant for but unfortunately it is posting the same comment under every post.  You can see the box working here: http://www.roomfor5.co.uk/item/6726

The website is php based and the code I am using is: " title="" url="" width="600" publish="true" >

I have also used this code without success: " width="600" publish="true" >

I know it's something to do with the xid attribute but I am stumped as to why it is duplicating:(

Comment: I am not sure why it has snipped the code I put in but it didn't look like that when I wrote it:/

Answer (score 1):

Hi when looking at the view source of your page I see this:

```
<fb:comments 
   xid="http://www.roomfor5.co.uk-<?=str_replace('/','-',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" 
   num_posts="2" 
   width="600" 
   publish="true" >
</fb:comments>
```

So the fb:comments tag is not getting rendered out fully.

Also on the rendered page, it says you haven't specified the url.  while there is a malformed xid= attribute, you really should have a url= attribute. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

```
Warning: this comments plugin is operating in 
compatibility mode, but has no posts yet. 
Consider specifying an explicit 'href' as 
suggested in the comments plugin documentation 
to take advantage of all plugin features.
```

**EDIT:**
For http://www.roomfor5.co.uk/item/6726, you have

```
<div 
  class="fb-comments" 
  data-href="http://www.roomfor5.co.uk" 
  data-num-posts="5" 
  data-width="600">
</div>
```

The data-href attribute should be `http://www.roomfor5.co.uk/item/6726` not `http://www.roomfor5.co.uk`

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I am using a template to generate the comment code so I can't specify a unique href tag as there are thousands and new ones being generated. Is there a way to get round this?

Comment: I have also had a look at that page and tried the suggestions but can't seem to get anywhere:/

Comment: You must play by Facebook's rules.  You must specify the href for the comments plugin to work. Also, try using the HTML5 code rather than the fb:comments tags.

Comment: Hi, I understand what your saying but there seems to be a fix for blogger, wordpress etc, people have been able to do it on these so why can't I? :( I really don't know anything about HTML5 code either :/

Comment: Using the HTML5 is just as easy as using the <fb:comments one, so it should be very natural for you to use.  See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/  When you click the "get code" button, it defaults to the HTML5 version.

Comment: But if I use that it needs me to add a href, I cannot do that because it would take me hours and it is not feasible??  I have managed to get it to work but it is still showing the incompatability box unfortunately but by not specifying a xid it points to the comment that the page is on and not just the website and it does not duplicate.

Comment: You MUST fix what facebook says is broken, or it wont work. Sorry. it needs an HREF on the newer plugins, not an XID. It's going to take you hours to fix the other issue, so upgrading to html5 should not be too hard.

Comment: Ok, I have done the html5 and I am still getting duplicate comments and now I get the error warning: http://www.mydomain.com is unreachable, so i am back to square one:(

Comment: <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.roomfor5.co.uk" data-num-posts="5" data-width="600"></div>  Here's the HTML you're serving for http://www.roomfor5.co.uk/item/6726.  The data-href= should be "http://www.roomfor5.co.uk/item/6726" to have comments just for that page.

Comment: But I can't do that for every single page, as you can see that is item 6726, I have thousands, surely there has to be an easy way to fetch the current url without having to specify it. It's just not feasible:/

Comment: Do it programmatically.  It looks like you're using PHP (me not a PHP guy) which is server-side scripting language...there's got to be a way for you to render out the html5 by script.  If it was classic ASP, it'd look like <% Response.Write("<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"" + Request.ServerVariables("URL") +"\"></div>") %>

Comment: Yes I suppose there might be (I don't know php either) but I would've liked it to have generated itself so I don't have to input it myself every time, I managed it with the like button.  I hoped this would have been as easy to implement:( Thanks for your help anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

If you click 'View source' you'll see the rendered HTML:

```
<fb:comments xid="http://www.roomfor5.co.uk-<?=str_replace('/','-',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" num_posts="2" width="600" publish="true" >
```

It looks like you're trying to specify a unique `xid` for the page but the server-side script is behaving like plain text.

Comment: Thanks James, any idea how I can rectify it?

Comment: @user1121660 If this is PHP, have you tried <?php echo str_replace(...); ?>